# Passing data from global memory to local memory in OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl, data-transfer

Let's say I have the following kernel:

```
__kernel void classify_data_points( __global float* data,
                                    __local float* datasegment)
{
    int gid0 = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);
    dataSegment[lid] = data[gid];
}
```

As it is seen, I want to take data from global memory into local memory. Is the size of local memory important to do this action at one time? I mean, dataSegment array size is 64bytes. Then, by this line 'dataSegment[lid] = data[gid]', can I assume whole 64bytes memory space is filled by data taken from global memory?(There is enough data in global memory) Or for 512 bytes long local memory, could we say same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the amount of memory copied depends on the workgroup size, not the size of datasegment. You cannot assume that 64 bytes of memory will be copied.

If you want to perform a copy as a single action, look at the [async_work_group_copy](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html) functions.

Comment: If your work groups are not multiple of data using async() function is the best choice. It is also valid for normal copies, so it should be used in any case.

Answer (score 3):

No, you need a barrier with a local memory fence after the code that writes local memory.  Something like this:

```
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

Only then can you be ensured that the local memory for your workgroup has been completely copied.  You also need to make sure your workgroups have enough work items to initialize all of the local memory for the workgroup (dataSegment in your case.)